# How unsafe is to "allow access to less secure apps" in Google?

Tags: linux, security, authentication, pidgin

I want to use Pidgin with Google Talk on Ubuntu but Google says:

> Google will continue to block sign-in attempts from the app you're
>   using because it has known security problems or is out of date. You
>   can continue to use this app by allowing access to less secure apps,
>   but this may leave your account vulnerable.

How bad is it to enable this setting?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to enable less secure apps to use pidgin.

You can use "App passwords" instead to create a high entropy password which will be used only by pidgin to access google's XMPP server.

https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which apps you use.  Some apps are easier to manipulate/hack than others.  You can see some of the "less secure" apps here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

If you're going to enable this setting, you should regularly monitor your account to check for unauthorized logins/access.  However, enabling this setting is fairly common; scanning to Gmail from some devices, for examples, requires you to enable this setting.